# Draw a grid with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

What would be the best way to draw a [grid like this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723002546/https://www.nctm.org/mathforum/) by using the SpriteKit 2D game engine?
Requirements:

- Input programatically the number of columns and rows (5x5, 10x3, 3x4 etc.).
- Draw it programmatically using something like `SKSpriteNode` or `SKShapeNode`, since just using images of a [square like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Square_-_black_simple.svg) doesn't seem very efficient to me.
- The squares should have a fixed size (let's say each is 40x40).
- The grid should be vertically and horizontally centred in the view.

I'm planning to use a `SKSpriteNode` (from an image) as a player moving in different squares in this grid.
So, I'll save in a 2 dimensional array the central point (x,y) of each square and then move from the player's current position to that position. If you have a better suggestion for this too, I'd like to hear it.

I would appreciate a solution in Swift (preferably 2.1), but Objective-C would do too. Planning on using this only on iPhone devices.
My question is close [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070387/building-a-chess-board-game-in-sprite-kit-using-swift). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use CGContext (Quartz) to draw the lines? Look at CGPaths. The only care you need to take is make sure that the coordinates co-incide. After all, sprites are sprites...

Comment: Does the grid need on the hole screen because the you should just divide the lengt of the screen throw the lengt of the grid you want.

Comment: To answer your question, no, the grid does not need to be on the whole screen.

Comment: Hey, Michael L! Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know how to use those CGPaths in an efficient way, but 0x141E's answer did that perfectly.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I suggest you implement the grid as a texture of an `SKSpriteNode` because Sprite Kit will renders the grid in a single draw call. Here's a example of how to do that:

```
class Grid:SKSpriteNode {
    var rows:Int!
    var cols:Int!
    var blockSize:CGFloat!

    convenience init?(blockSize:CGFloat,rows:Int,cols:Int) {
        guard let texture = Grid.gridTexture(blockSize: blockSize,rows: rows, cols:cols) else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(texture: texture, color:SKColor.clear, size: texture.size())
        self.blockSize = blockSize
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
    }

    class func gridTexture(blockSize:CGFloat,rows:Int,cols:Int) -> SKTexture? {
        // Add 1 to the height and width to ensure the borders are within the sprite
        let size = CGSize(width: CGFloat(cols)*blockSize+1.0, height: CGFloat(rows)*blockSize+1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
        }
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        let offset:CGFloat = 0.5
        // Draw vertical lines
        for i in 0...cols {
            let x = CGFloat(i)*blockSize + offset
            bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: 0))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: size.height))
        }
        // Draw horizontal lines
        for i in 0...rows {
            let y = CGFloat(i)*blockSize + offset
            bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size.width, y: y))
        }
        SKColor.white.setStroke()
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 1.0
        bezierPath.stroke()
        context.addPath(bezierPath.cgPath)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return SKTexture(image: image!)
    }

    func gridPosition(row:Int, col:Int) -> CGPoint {
        let offset = blockSize / 2.0 + 0.5
        let x = CGFloat(col) * blockSize - (blockSize * CGFloat(cols)) / 2.0 + offset
        let y = CGFloat(rows - row - 1) * blockSize - (blockSize * CGFloat(rows)) / 2.0 + offset
        return CGPoint(x:x, y:y)
    }
}
```

And here's how to create a grid and add a game piece to the grid

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to: SKView) {
        if let grid = Grid(blockSize: 40.0, rows:5, cols:5) {
            grid.position = CGPoint (x:frame.midX, y:frame.midY)
            addChild(grid)

            let gamePiece = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
            gamePiece.setScale(0.0625)
            gamePiece.position = grid.gridPosition(row: 1, col: 0)
            grid.addChild(gamePiece)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

To determine which grid square was touched, add this to `init`

```
self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

and this to the `Grid` class:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let position = touch.location(in:self)
        let node = atPoint(position)
        if node != self {
            let action = SKAction.rotate(by:CGFloat.pi*2, duration: 1)
            node.run(action)
        }
        else {
            let x = size.width / 2 + position.x
            let y = size.height / 2 - position.y
            let row = Int(floor(x / blockSize))
            let col = Int(floor(y / blockSize))
            print("\(row) \(col)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate the solution, @0x141E! It's exactly what I was looking for. Really cool how you got `SpriteKit` to render the grid in a single draw. Additional thank you for the `gridPosition` function, it's better than what I had in mind.

Comment: How would you differentiate every box in the grid? Say I add skspritenodes as children of Grid class, how would I use touches began for every box in the grid?

Comment: Adding touchesBegan to `Grid` class does not work. You need to add it to the node instance which is added to the grid.I suspect this is because you're adding the box in the grid as a child of the entire grid sprite. So Instead we need to inherit `SKSpriteNode` in a different class for every box and override `touchesBegan` over there. That's what worked for me. I figured this out the hard way. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Boggartfly see the update to the `touchesBegan` method.

Comment: Would it be better to use a `SKTileMapNode` for this?

Comment: I did some experimenting and you can render a grid in a single draw call using a `SKTileMapNode` as well. It took only a few lines of code so it might be more convenient